# apache 2.4.6 not recognizing header type for css or js with php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, wordpress

I have migrated my wordpress site to AWS but the css is not being loaded and there are some js errors

here is the site on AWS http://www.houseofsr.co.uk/

the error i see is

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.houseofsr.co.uk/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.2".`

I am using EC2 with php7 as php-fpm and apache2.4

here is my config file

**apache**

```
#grep -v "#" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin info@houseofsr.co.uk
ServerName www.houseofsr.co.uk:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/javascript .js
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

**php7**

```
#egrep -v ";|^$" /etc/php.ini
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = -1
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = ""
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
```

**headers**

```
    $ sudo httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
```

I created a brand [new wordpress site](http://bangla-relief-1256586364.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/), fresh installation. these setups also have loadbalancers in front. It has same issue with css.

[through loadbalancer](http://bangla-relief-1256586364.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/style.css)

[direct link on webserver](http://ec2-35-177-165-178.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/style.css)

**UPDATE**

it seems liek it has to do something with my htaccess file and `php-fpm`. ive come across  [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/450628/apache-2-4-php-fpm-proxypassmatch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054617/mod-rewrite-in-2-4-25-triggering-fcgi-primary-script-unknown-error-in-php-fpm) but its not helping.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [L,P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NS]
```

this [url](http://ec2-35-177-165-178.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg) now gives `oops not found page` but not everything is loading

Comment: try this link and check http://bangla-relief-1256586364.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/style.css the response header is `text/html`

Comment: @Fabian thats not possible, check the wordpress, fresh install http://ec2-35-177-165-178.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: not only for css and js files, even for images the response header is Content-Type:text/html ( http://ec2-35-177-165-178.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg ). To be honest: I would use Debian instead of Amazon Linux

Comment: what does this mean it... it does not have required packages installed?

Comment: please post /etc/mime.types

Comment: another try: remove `MIMEMagicFile conf/magic` from Apache conf, run apachectl configtest and then restart Apache

Comment: To answer your question in the comment: No, it does not look like a package is missing. I would investigate mod_mime and mod_mime_magic

Comment: @Fabian I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have updated the file `.../conf.d/php.conf` with the following contents and my `htaccess` fiel is empty

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .phtml .html .css .js
AddType text/html .php

# This is to forward all PHP to php-fpm.
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
 </FilesMatch>

 # Set some proxy properties (the string "unique-domain-name-string" should match
 # the one set in the FilesMatch directive.
 <Proxy fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000>
   ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=240
 </Proxy>

 # If the php file doesn't exist, disable the proxy handler.
 # This will allow .htaccess rewrite rules to work and
 # the client will see the default 404 page of Apache
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
 RewriteRule (.*) - [H=text/html]
```